# Where I can look for android: windowBackground in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, mobile-application, android-drawable-importer

Because I couldn't see in my android version Imageview feature.Is that because of android version?

Comment: That is a theme attribute, not an `ImageView` attribute. You would set it with an `<item>` in the `<style>` that defines your theme, not in a layout `<ImageView>` tag. Are you looking for just plain `android:background`, maybe?

Comment: yes exactly android background

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.